# which file do i need to edit frm backend to makes changes to home page (frontend)

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a website and i am not able to find the home page file in backend, i recently changed my theme, and all the pages in the cms table have not be updated automatically, just please which file do i need to edit to make the following changes for instance, change the sentence in the banner of home page.
I have a website and i am not able to find the home page file in backend, i recently changed my theme, and all the pages in the cms table have not be updated automatically, just please which file do i need to edit to make the following changes for instance, change the sentence in the banner of home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now if you wish to have your custom designed homepage follow the steps below:

1) Go to system->configuration->General->web->default pages and note down the page it is pointing to.
2)Go to cms->pages and search for the title there
3)Go in the content section and paste the following code

```
<p>{{block type="core/template" template="page/your_page.phtml"}}</p>
```

4)Create a file in your codebase in default template/page folder with the name 'your_page.phtml'

Do everything in this file and it will reflect on the frontend. Don't forget to clear your cache

Comment: This would surely work, but i want to edit the existing homepage, like for instance, visit www.blendurtrend.com, there is some text write on it, like the footer contact details or slider text, i want to edit and change all of these.

Comment: for footer if you have your codebase just go to template/page/html/footer.phtml. You will find the footer code written there, change as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in magento you find home page here.

1. `System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default Pages ->  CMS Home Page` (See Which Page Currently set Home Page)
2. `CMS -> Pages` (Open the page which is set in step-1 to edit)

Comment: this worked out, but but i want to edit the existing homepage, like for instance, visit www.blendurtrend.com, there is some text write on it, like the footer contact details or slider text, i want to edit and change all of these.

Comment: You can find current Homepage there and then make to edit what you want.